# Mysql command from host not taking change

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to run a script on a mysql container, but when I am running it from the host it does not make the needed changes.

The command that I run on my docker host is

```
docker exec  mysql mysql -u root -ppassword perks_camp < ./1.0.1.sql
```

it says `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.` which is expected, and it seems that the script inside is ran, but when I log in to the container's db, the changes are not applied.

On the other hand, when I copy the file to the container and run the same command from inside the container `mysql -u root -ppassword perks_camp < ./1.0.1.sql`
, the changes are applied.

What is wrong here? What am I missing?

Comment: stupid comment from my part but sometime.... : Is it the same container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup

```
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

Restore

```
cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE
```

https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb